# Using Application Insights for capturing details of user actions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

A customer has asked we start tracking user and administration actions on our website for security purposes.

> e.g. AdminUser {id: 3} impersonated user {id: 5} on 2015-08-04T12:00:00

The thought was we would publish that data using the Application Insights SDK. Our customer would then be able to monitor these events through the Azure portal.

Given the data retention policies of Application Insights, we would enable Continuous Export of data to table storage if a forensic analysis needed to be conducted past the 30 day cut-off.

Are there any obvious red flags to using Application Insights to provide visibility into these security details?

Answer (score 1):

No, that should just work.
Here is how you create events: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/
Note that if you also want to add custom properties to events there is a limit on number of unique property names per application. Currently it is 200 but that may decrease in the future.

Comment: to update this answer, the default retention is now 90 days, so if you only need that much data you wouldn't need to do continuous export.  and the 200 property names limit is also no longer a thing.